# postgres: taking backup and restore as different user: Should i use both --username and --role along with --no-owner

Tags: postgresql

I have read few posts regarding this topic

Currently for backing up I do the following. My owner of the database is `owner1`

```
pg_dump --username=postgres -Fc dbname -f db_name.dump
```

I heard that any superuser (here postgres) or even user with read permission can take backup. It need not be the owner of the database.

Now I want to restore with a different user who is also a `superuser` (we will call him `owner2`).

I have database called `owner2_db` created by `owner2`

```
pg_restore -v -d owner2_db --no-owner --username=owner2 --role=owner2 db_name.dump
```

Because some places I saw they don't use `--role=owner2`. So in my case what's the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

If you connect to the database as role `x`, there is no need to run an extra `SET ROLE x`, so you can omit the `--role` option. It is useful if you want the objects to be owned by a `NOLOGIN` role.

When restoring as a different user, and the original roles don't exist on the destination cluster, you may want to use the `-x` and `-O` options.

Comment: `It is useful if you want the objects to be owned by a NOLOGIN role` : what do you mean by `NOLOGIN role.` Do you mean `roles which don't exist on the destination cluster`

Comment: A PostgreSQL role that is not allowed to log into the database. See the `CREATE DATABASE` documentation.

Comment: `When restoring as a different user, and the original roles don't exist on the destination cluster`: SO in my case `owner1` = `original roles don't exist on the destination cluster` and `owner2` = `restoring as a different user` Am in right

Comment: Yes. That's why I recommend `-x` and `-O`, so that ownership and permissions don't get restored.